# Prevent Wordpress from creating individual size images

Tags: images

I have installed a compressing plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-compress-images/) in Wordpress to minimize the file size of all the images that I upload. Works really well, the only problem is the following:

If I create a new page, insert a picture and resize it manually in the editor Wordpress seems to create a new version of the picture with exactly the resolution that I have chosen. For instance I have a newly created file called airline-768x447.png in my uploads folder that was apparently created by Wordpress when I resized the original image in the editor to this size.

The problem is that this newly created file doesn't get compressed by the plugin and therefore its file size is way bigger than it should be.

Why isn't wordpress just using the original file and just resizes it using css or the width and height attributes? Is there any option to turn off this behavior where Wordpress seems to create images with individual size?

I have searched for quite a while but couldn't find any solutions. Thanks :)

Comment: Using the image editor you can do more than just resize an image, and using CSS on the frontend isn't reliable. CSS won't handle cropping, contrast changes, flipping horizontally, etc. In all honesty this sounds like a bug in the plugin rather than something WP Core is doing wrong

Comment: What would you _want_ to happen in such case? You explicitly use UI to resize image, but want image not to resize?

Answer (score 0):

You will get more details if you Google this : `add_image_size()`

Or Reading this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Each theme or plugin can register new image size that are create autmatically when a media (image) is insert in a post or in the media uploader.

You can remove them if you want with the function `remove_image_size`...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can go into options and for the default images sizes you can just set the value to 0 which in return will disable the image generation for that case.

> You can stop WordPress from generating default image sizes by visiting Settings » Media in WordPress admin area. There you will see default image sizes predefined by WordPress. You need to set these sizes to 0 which will prevent WordPress from generating default image sizes when you upload a new image.
> [As seen on WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-generating-image-sizes/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20stop%20WordPress%20from,you%20upload%20a%20new%20image.)